# I cannot run crontab as root

Tags: command-line, cron

Hello my problem is that I can not run script as root in /home/user/onzulin/backup.sh the content of the script is this:

**backup.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
tar -cpvzf "gamesyap_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/backup.snap /home/web/web/html/*
tar -cpvzf "gym_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/gym.snap /home/web/web/gym/*
tar -cpvzf "juegos_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/juegos.snap /home/web/web/juegos/*
tar -cpvzf "meteotemplate_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/meteotemplate.snap /home/web/web/meteotemplate/*
tar -cpvzf "prueba_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/prueba.snap /home/web/web/prueba/*
tar -cpvzf "test_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/test.snap /home/web/web/test/*
tar -cpvzf "tienda_`date +%d%m%y`.tar.gz" -g /home/onzulin/backup/snap/tienda.snap /home/web/web/tienda/*
```

## bases de datos MySQL de cada web

```bsh
mysqldump -u root -ppassword gamesyap > gamesyap.sql
mysqldump -u root -ppassword gym > gym.sql 
mysqldump -u root -ppassword juegos > juegos.sql
mysqldump -u root -ppassword meteo > meteo.sql
mysqldump -u root -ppassword prueba > prueba.sql
mysqldump -u root -ppassword test > test.sql
mysqldump -u root -ppassword tienda > tienda.sql
```

## todos los archivos con chown onzulin:onzulin

```bsh
sudo chown -R onzulin:onzulin .
```

the content in `sudo crontab -e` is

```bsh
# m h  dom mon dow   command
48 13 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet --renew-hook "/bin/systemctl reload nginx"
27 11 * * * /home/onzulin/backup/backup.sh
```

how can you see renew a ssl certificate without problem. 
I would like to know why my script does not work, regards.

Comment: `mysqldump -u root -ppassword gamesyap > gamesyap.sql` Sorry but no; that is a security problem. See the manual for mysqldump and the `--defaults-extra-file` option.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo systemctl status cron`? Did you remember to leave a blank line at the end?

Comment: You should use full path names in the `tar` files.

Comment: Use absolute path for used binary commands. Cron don't known the $PATH.